# Умножение матриц PHP, ускорить

Tags: php, матрицы

Есть необходимость произвести миллионы умножений матриц(вложенные циклы for) для обучения нейронной сети.
Есть ли какая либо библиотека или какой то способ увеличить производительность этих вычислений?

на данный момент полный цикл расчета занимает чуть меньше часа.
таких циклов нужно прокрутить десятки тысяч.
Экспериментальным путем установил, что цикл for на 20% быстрее чем foreach. Буду признателен  за любой совет, который поможет ускорить выполнение задачи.

Снова пробовал улучшить функцию производящую умножение для тестов взял вектор(4096 значений) и матрицу(4096 * 4096) все заполнено рандомными floatв пределах +-1 итого цикл должен произвести 16,7М вычислений.
исходные вектор и матрица имеют вид:

```
[х1]   [w11,w12,w13]
[х2]   [w21,w22,w23]
[х3]   [w31,w32,w33]
```

первая функция работает 2.45сек и делает такие вычисления:

```
y1 = x1*w11 + x2*w12 + x3*w13
y2 = x1*w21 + x2*w22 + x3*w23
y3 = x1*w31 + x2*w32 + x3*w33
```

вторая функция работает 11.5сек и делает такие вычисления:

```
y1 = x1*w11 + x1*w21 + x1*w31
y2 = x2*w11 + x2*w21 + x2*w31
y3 = x3*w11 + x3*w21 + x3*w31
```

```
function multiply1($vector,$matrix){//2.45 seconds
    for ($y=0; $y < count($matrix[0]); $y++) { 
        $sum = 0;
        $m = $matrix[$y];
        for ($x=0; $x < count($vector); $x++) { 
            $sum += $vector[$x] * $m[$x];    
        }
        $result_vector[$y] = $sum;
    }
    return $result_vector;
}
function multiply2($vector,$matrix){//11.5 seconds
    for ($y=0; $y < count($matrix[0]); $y++) { 
        $sum = 0;
        for ($x=0; $x < count($vector); $x++) { 
            $sum += $vector[$x] * $matrix[$x][$y];    
        }
        $result_vector[$y] = $sum;
    }
    return $result_vector;
}
```

как можно оптимизировать вторую функцию?

Comment: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/ffi

Comment: Почему для этой задачи был выбран именно PHP? А первое, что приходит в голову, это задействовать GPU. Что-то [подобное](https://github.com/BourneSuper/matrix)

Comment: счас тут все свои хрустальные шары достанут, и нагадают вам как ускорить ваши циклы.

Comment: у вас там может и затык то не в умножении, а в том откуда и как вы данные в свои матрицы загружаете. Код приводите, больше данных давайте, разерности данных укажите и прочее. Без деталей никто вам ничего не оптимизирует тут. десятки тысяч на миллионы умножений матриц как уже написали на гпу хорошо распараллелятся

Comment: тестировал каждый этап(получение данных, обработка, запись результата) на скорость выполнения, львиную долю занимает именно умножение. Остальными величинами можно пренебречь т.к. на каждые 40 мин вычислений 1запись данных в базу(пару мин) и 1 чтение(1сек).

Comment: @Максим У меня эти две функции отличаются не так значительно, как у вас. Какая версия PHP? Попробуйте также вынести count() из циклов.